# Possible collision/conflict between 2 javascripts?

Tags: javascript

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/gLCjy/14/

One javascript ensures copy-paste value from above input field. User presses and holds ctrl, then click on field below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").on('click', function(e) {
var name1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').val();
if(e.ctrlKey) $(this).val(name1);
});
});
```

Second javascript changes input field value to 1 if in certain input fields value is entered or changed

```
<input type="text" name="is_row_changed[]" id="is_row_changed1" size="1">
<script>
$(".row_changed1").on("change", function () {
document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 1;
});
</script>
```

html input fields are like this

```
<input type="text" name="date_year[]" id="date_year1" class="row_changed1" value="" size="2">
```

If I enter (or copy-paste) values without ctrl+click then all works as necessary.

However if I hold ctrl and click in field then value is copied and appears in the field, but value here `<input type="text" name="is_row_changed[]" id="is_row_changed1" size="1">` does not change.

Enter something in left top field. Right top field value changes to 1. That is ok.

Then press and hold ctrl and click in left bottom field. Left bottom field value becomes the same as left top field's value. This is also ok.

But right bottom field value does not change. This is the problem... Actually no idea. Need advice to which direction to go....

Comment: Hi, from what I understand it seems you'd like a way to track changes to a table, is that correct? If so, do you need those class/id names or can I change them to make it a little easier?

Comment: I updated code in example. I mean 2 rows with multiple input fields. If I enter something in the first row, then right last input field value becomes 1. If I enter smt in the second row then last input field value becomes 1. But if I enter smt in the first row, then ctrl+click in field just below, then last input field value does not change. Possible more understandable if to see example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because change event doesnot get triggered on programatically assined values. You can manually trigger it when you assign the value to the textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").on('click', function (e) {
        var name1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').val();
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            $(this).val(name1).trigger('change'); //Trigger the change event here.

        };
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgUck/)